# How can vscode view detailed usage information for certain python package library functions? (like the sum function in pytorch)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I used to use [spyder-IDE](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) for python programming, for example, I used the `sum` function in pytorch library, `torch.sum()`, using keyboard shortcut "ctrl+I" to quickly see how to use the function, input and output parameters, examples code and so on. However, with the latest pylance_v2021.9.1+vscode 1.6+pytorch 1.9 you cannot see the detailed help information, it seems that you can only see it by typing `torch.sum()?` in the terminal, Is there some extensions that provides this feature? Thank you!

[Official vscode says](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/pytorch-support#_intellisense-through-the-pylance-language-server) (IntelliSense through the Pylance language server) that use pylance+pytorch 1.8.1 or later release support mouse hover to see pytroch detailed preview information, but I use the latest version of vscode 1.6+pytorch 1.9 but it doesn't work, it only shows function signature hints, not detailed help information.

- 2021.9.17 update, Description example update:

This image is the detailed help information of "[torch.sum](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sum.html)" obtained by [spyder-IDE](https://www.spyder-ide.org/)
[image]

However, it is not easy to get such detailed help information in vscode, but only the function signature shown below(left), unless you type `torch.sum?` in the [python interactive window](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py) to see the full help information every time(right). Moreover, the full "Docstring" is not rendered, so it is not easy to read visually like spyder-IDE.
[image]

The above two use the same python environment,the various versions used are： vscoder1.6+pytorch1.9+(microsoft)python_v2021.9.1230869389+pylance_v2021.9.2, spyderIDE4.0

Answer (score 0):

Have you click this?

[image]

Then it should be like this:

[image]

the `sum` would be like this:

[image]

But if you want to get more information, it depends on the docs, such as `AdaptiveAvgPool2d`:

[image]

But the `sum` does not contains that:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, you haven't fully understood what I mean due to my lack of expression, of course my doubts are still not solved, I'll screenshot it for you too, I really wish vscode could get detailed help information like spyder-IDE, not just show simple function signature information! But the python interactive window in vscode, enter the `torch.sum?` is able to get its full details (every time I have to enter this is very tedious), I hope there is a convenient similar plug-ins or tools to display the information in full, but, thanks for your answer!

Comment: See above question 2021.9.17 update,But thank you very much for your answer! @Steven-MSFT